# Misplaced Parenthesis

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Background**

Ok so I've been working on a way of stopping a form from refreshing but still Posting, and then showing a JS alert.

**Problem**

I don't have enough Java Script experience to piece two pieces of code together, the first being an Ajax Post and the second being a OnClick event.

I can't seem to get the parentheses to match up correctly and/or get the syntax right.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Event Listener for form submit
    $('#form1').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Form Submitted'); //Debug line
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'indextest2.php',
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            error: function(){console.log('Ajax Error'); //Debug Line
            success: function(response) {
                console.log('Ajax Success'); //Debug Line

                $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
            bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
                console.log("Alert Callback");
            });
        });

     }

     }

     }
```

As you can guess it is the closing parentheses i'm having problems with.

Any help would be great.

Comment: use something like Notepad++, jsHint, or even an error console from now on.

Comment: you can follow the indentation of the code to place the parenthesis

Comment: I've been trying all sorts of programs this afternoon, so far Netbeans, Visual Studio and Web Storm. Web Storm has been the most useful but it's still pretty complicated compared to DreamWeaver. I'll give JsHint, thanks @dandavis.

Comment: firebug in particular is usually friendlier/more specific about these kind of syntax errors than most error consoles.

Comment: Ok maybe it is time to switch to Firefox, been holding out in favour of Chrome for a while now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need some formatting, then you can see what's not closed and add the appropriate braces and parenthesis:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //Event Listener for form submit
  $('#form1').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('Form Submitted'); //Debug line
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'indextest2.php',
      data: $("#form1").serialize(),
      error: function() {console.log('Ajax Error');}, //<-- Add this
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('Ajax Success'); //Debug Line
        $(document).on("click", ".alert", function(e) {
          bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
            console.log("Alert Callback");
          });
        })
      }
    }); // < -- Add this
  }); // <-- Add this
}); // <-- Add this
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i will make the changes you suggest. Like i said i am still pretty new to JavaScript and i was sure when to close with a "});" or just a "}".

Comment: In this case, you're passing functions into other functions as parameters, so you need a closing `)` to those function calls.  Yes, confusing - Using a good IDE with syntax highlighting helps.  For every opening parenthesis, there must be a closing parenthesis.  For every opening curly brace, there must be a closing curly brace.

Comment: Thank you for your help, your solution worked great! I'm going to try as suggested by other users using Firebug. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `}` and a `,` here:

```
error: function(){console.log('Ajax Error'); //Debug Line
```

It should have brackets to close the function and a comma to separate the next line/property, like:

```
error: function(){console.log('Ajax Error'); }, //Debug Line
                                             ^^
```

Last, but not least you need to close some other functions...

**Try this:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Event Listener for form submit
    $('#form1').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Form Submitted'); //Debug line
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'indextest2.php',
            data: $("#form1").serialize(),
            error: function () {
                console.log('Ajax Error');
            }, //Debug Line
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('Ajax Success'); //Debug Line

                $(document).on("click", ".alert", function (e) {
                    bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function () {
                        console.log("Alert Callback");
                    });
                });
            }
        }); // added by me
    }); // added by me
}); // added by me
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I don't mean to sound ungrateful but your solution required a tweak. The removal of one ";" in the third closing  brace. Thank you again.

Comment: @DanCundy, you are right! I should have not put `;` inside a object! All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

Where is the `alert function` defined?

Should this

```
bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
  console.log("Alert Callback");
});
```

actually be this?

```
alert("Hello world!");
console.log("Alert Callback");
```